# how to navigate between screens in flutter using navigator if i use material app with home property?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to navigate and trunsfer data between two differrent dart files in flutter,but as I read in another stackoverflow question I cant do this,because I use home property in my mainpage file,but idk how to change my programm and dont use home,or how to make it without routes.
First File dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'fillpage.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(Glavpage());
}

class Glavpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Glavpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GlavpageState createState() => _GlavpageState();
}

class _GlavpageState extends State<Glavpage> {
  var dList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      dList.add("kek");
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
          '/': (BuildContext context) => new Glavpage(),
          '/fillpage': (BuildContext context) => new zmist(),
        },
        title: 'NoteApplication',
        home: Scaffold(

          appBar: PreferredSize(
              child: AppBar(
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              ),
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0)),
          body: Container(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(23, 34, 59, 1),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
               // SizedBox(height: 50),
                Container(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(23, 34, 59, 1),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          "Notes",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1),
                            fontSize: 72,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                        child: Text(
                          "Never Settle",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 0.25),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Container(
                        child: Icon(Icons.search, size: 40,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1)),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 30),
                      Container(
                        child: Icon(Icons.menu, size: 40,
                            color:Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height:1,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    margin:EdgeInsets.only(top:5,),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(23, 34, 59, 1),
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                      const Divider(),
                      itemCount: dList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 8),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 60,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1)
                                        .withOpacity(0.2)),
                                borderRadius:
                                BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                dList[index],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/fillpage');
          },
              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(23, 34, 59, 1),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(side: BorderSide(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 103, 104, 1),
                  width: 2,
                  style: BorderStyle.solid
              ), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 103, 104, 1),)),
        ));
  }
}
```

Second file dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(zmist());
}

class zmist extends StatefulWidget {
  const zmist({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _zmistState createState() => _zmistState();
}

class _zmistState extends State<zmist> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            child: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            ),
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0.0)),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(23, 34, 59, 1),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_sharp,
                          size: 40, color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 230),
                    Container(
                      child:Icon(Icons.check,
                          size: 40, color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1)),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child:Icon(Icons.share,
                          size: 40, color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1)),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child:Icon(Icons.menu,
                          size: 40, color: Color.fromRGBO(107, 119, 141, 1)),
                    ),


                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to navigate from Glavepage to Zmist then add a button in Glavepage and write following code-

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => zmist()),
})
```

and remove following lines from second file-

```
void main() {
 runApp(zmist());
}
```